# Css 3 animation when page loads

Tags: css

How to get it my page to load like this when everything on the page is loaded?
example: http://www.creabox.es/themes/verde/index_images.php

My code:

```
#h1count {opacity: 0;
   transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}



#h1count {
        font-family: 'League Gothic';
    src: url( 'leaguegothic-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('leaguegothic-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('leaguegothic-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('leaguegothic-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('leaguegothic-regular-webfont.svg#league_gothicregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size:70px;
    line-height:70px;
    opacity: 1;
```

Comment: Don’t. That website is blank without JavaScript, and splash screens of any kind are bad UX.

Answer (score 0):

the esiest solution is to put the Animation in the class and write in the css

for example

```
.animation {
   animation: anim-1 0.2s ...
   -webkit-animation: anim-1 ...
}
```

and control the loading of html elements via Javascript via libraries or plugins ...
there are plenty of them out there

or you can use JQuery Method $(element).load(function(){}

and be sure everythi8ng loaded

you can use $(window).load(function(){} for entire page loading and after that add the animation class to your elements

so the animation will run after the page load